# What would an artificial galaxy look like?

Tags: galactic

Suppose there is an advanced type 3 civilization that has the capability of creating entire artificial galaxies (this means they can create stars, planets or even black holes).
But how exactly would that artificial galaxy look like from afar? How different could they make an artifial galaxy that is functional, and how would that civilization organize it in order for there to be perfect order.

(Note: Images are welcome)

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding.SE!  We're glad you could join us!  When you have a moment, please [click here](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6388/welcome-to-worldbuilding-se?noredirect=1) to learn more about our culture and take our [tour].  Please note that this question is likely to be closed as [primarily opinion-based](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6436#6437) because there isn't one best answer.  We can't know what rules of orbital mechanics they can use, and they can do anything they want within those rules.  You'll find more in our [help].

Comment: See for example [The World Islands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_World_(archipelago)), an artificial archipelago, and [Palm Jumeirah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palm_Jumeirah), an artificial peninsula, built by enterprising enterprises in Dubai. They don't look much like natural archipelagoes and peninsulas. As for the question as asked, since you want your galaxy *functional* and in *perfect order*, it would certainly help if you could list what are the top three required functionalities, and if you could describe what is expected from an ordered galaxy.

Comment: Why would it look any different from a natural galaxy?

Comment: It would have a *"Made in [insert some country here]"* tag attached to it.

Answer (score 3):

I can't tell you exactly what this galaxy will be like. I simply don't know enough about this specific future or this K-3 civilisation or why they are doing this. I can tell you how this galaxy might differ from our own in a few key ways.

1. it is quite likely to be entirely simulated. Even if you CAN move stars, create black-holes ETC... Doens't mean you should. if you are trying to build a place for people to live it's FAR more efficient to simply simulate the whole thing, you can also get away with interesting phenomena and technologies that simply aren't possible in the real world. If you want to shoot fireballs on a giant candy planet with darth vader you can do that in a simulated reality. if it is simulated literally everything is simply a matter of opinion for the civilisation in question, so ignore the rest of the list.
2. If very good FTL-travel (especially travel built on "inter-stellar highways") has been invented it might be long and thin with two (or possibly more) large thin galactic arms, this will slightly reduce the galaxies over-all temperature which is useful if the majority of technology still obeys the laws of thermodynamics as it increases the efficiency of most systems.
3. If very poor or no FTL-travel has been invented your galaxy is likely to be spherical to allow for 'fast' communication and travel between systems. This spherical shape will be hard but not impossible to maintain, stars will be "nudged occasionaly" and it's likely that dark-matter and other useless mass will be evacuated from the galaxy to slow down all the orbits. Think globular 
   clusters https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globular_cluster but more regular and more managed.
4. It is likely to have many more red-dwarf stars, as opposed to main-sequence stars. Red dwarf stars are longer lived and allow for easier star-lifting.
5. It is likely to have no (or few) planets. Planets are simply not an efficient way of converting mass into living area. Instead you'll likely have mega-structures like Dyson swarms, ring worlds, rung worlds and the like. Most planets that do exist are likely to be shell worlds. Indeed this must be the case for your civilisation to be a true K-3. Weather planets are built first then disassembled or never built in the first place is up to you
6. saying all that it's possible that stars don't exist. Stars are not too efficient at converting mass to energy https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t-O-Qdh7VvQ black holes are better and it's possible that your civilisation adopts them or some other method to fill a star-like role.
7. Stellar density is likely to remain constant throughout. Natural galaxies tend to have regions of high and low stellar density (the number of stars per unit volume of space.) this is bad as regions of low stellar density have longer communications times and regions of high stellar density increase the chance of collisions. If gravity manipulation is sufficiently advanced (big if) The stars might even be "packed" that is to say positioned in a face centred cubic arrangement (with a large distance between stars) and completely stationary unless being moved.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the advanced civilization wants to build an artificial galaxy that takes the shape of a spiral galaxy. Our galaxy is a spiral, so it's a matter of convenience and simplicity to assume the advanced aliens will want something similar.

What will the artificial galaxy look like from afar? This is easy. It will look like almost any other spiral galaxy.

The other parts of your question are little trickier to answer. Namely, organizing the artificial galaxy to be both functional and perfect. Assuming the advanced aliens are limited to travelling below the speed of light and their idea of perfection is geometric regularity, then they will arrange the stars orbiting the centre of their artificial galaxy to be placed at equal distances apart and strung along their galactic orbits.

This to facilitate easy interstellar travel. The stars will also be arranged in their orbits to be as close as gravitationally possible. Stars in natural galaxies are situated in what are effectively random orbits and at random distances apart. If stars in the artificial galaxy are organized as suggested here this will make travel functionally easier and more efficient than in a galaxy like ours.

Effectively the artificial galaxy enjoy much higher stellar densities and this will make interstellar journeys shorter. They will also require less energy. While for aliens advanced enough to build galaxies this may not be of much concern, it will make star travel less inconvenient.

Astronomers in other galaxies will however notice the artificial galaxy has stars packed close together in high density configurations and the stars will be strung like pearls along common galactic orbits. This sufficiently unlike normal galaxies that they will suspect this arrangement is due to technological intervention by intelligent aliens.

Answer (score 1):

It heavily depends on the race's preferences, where and how they get their materials, their idea of the amount of time they want to spend on traveling and if they've beaten entropy.

Building a Galaxy from scratch is going to be a massive undertaking and bringing in all the material and energy into one place and all going in the right directions at the right distances. Even for an advanced civilization the amount of wasted energy and speed at which the universe would decay faster would likely not be worth it unless they've beaten entropy.

Ignoring race preferences it is likely they'll be going for efficient first: Rather than a simple spiral Galaxy, they'll try to build everything as close to eachother as possible to reduce the amount of travel time and energy expenditure for traveling. They'll either build it as a disk around the center to make orbits more easily controlled or if they have the know-how they'll simply build a giant sphere around the center. Why waste building a massive spiral Galaxy if you can have all those stars, planets and black holes "close" together in one place? It certainly makes travel and communications a lot easier.

Answer (score 1):

**It's unnaturally dark.**

Let's say a solar powered type 3 civilisation has wrapped every star in the galaxy in Dyson swarms. A trillion stars and every one is orbited by a trillion huge solar panels, converting a significant fraction of the stars' visible light into other forms of energy.

People in the galaxy still have all the light they need; they either live on the inside of a swarm, or they turn on a lightbulb. But they don't like to waste a lot of light by letting it leave a solar system.

Assuming the laws of thermodynamics still apply, all that energy doesn't just vanish; you can expect there to be forms of energy with higher entropy than visible light radiating out of the galaxy. Most likely the machines that use all that power produce heat and maintain thermal equilibrium by radiating infrared light.

So perhaps the galaxy was almost invisible to 19th century astronomers, but is now highly visible to a 21st century astronomer with a big infrared telescope.